# Displaying a div on a button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, button

I want to display a particular div on the click of a button

My asp code is as follows

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />

<div runat="server" id="signup" Visible="false">Some Content </div>
```

Now in the CodeBehind i have written the following code

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Visible = false;
        signup.Visible = true;
    }
```

But every time i get the error as

```
the name signup does't exist in the current context
```

i am not able to figure out the problem in the code..

Answer (score 4):

You probably have wrong `html` for the `div`, you can also use `style="visible:none"` instead of  Visible="false"

*Change*

```
visible:"false"
```

*To*

```
Visible="false"
```

Comment: I presume you mean style="display:none" or style="visibility:hidden".

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done through JavaScript, I believe in the onClientClick attribute of the button. I'm currently searching for the code to jog my own